# Sort PHP foreach() loop in Cakephp

Tags: php, loops, sorting

I'm slowly learning PHP, and I need some help with sorting through a foreach() loop. Currently, this loop grabs an ID and Name from a database table and displays it in a list, however, I'm having problems sorting that list in alphabetical order. This is what is looks like now where all the records are retrieved and presented in a neat list:

```
<?php foreach ($disabilities as $disability):?>
        <option value=<?=($disability->id)?>><?=($disability->name)?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this is what I have tried:

```
<?php myArray = array($disabilities)
      sort($disabilities)  
      foreach ($disabilities as $disability): ?>
           <option value=<?=($disability->id)?>><?=($disability->name)?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any tips on whether I'm on the right/wrong path would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by two ways.
1) sort this while querying from the database.
2) sort arrays in php, here is an example code for sorting in php.

```
//stdclass object arrays to simple array
$disabilities = json_decode(json_encode($object), True);
$sortArray = array(); 

foreach($disabilities as $disability){ 
    foreach($disability as $key=>$value){ 
        if(!isset($sortArray[$key])){ 
            $sortArray[$key] = array(); 
        } 
        $sortArray[$key][] = $value; 
    } 
} 

$orderby = "name"; //change this to whatever key you want to apply sorting for
array_multisort($sortArray[$orderby], SORT_ASC, $disabilities);
```

hope it works for you

**Edit:** As I have changed it from stdClass Object to array now you will echo like this

```
echo $disability['name'];
```

Comment: It works! Thanks so much for your help! I wouldn't have though to use JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function add user defined comparison function.

```
$obj = (object) array(
  ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'Ronda'],
  ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'Aba'],
  ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'Mac']
);

//convert obj to array usort only accept array
$disabilities = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true); 

//define custom function
function sortByName($a, $b) {
  //compare two strings
  return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

//sort using usort before use
usort($disabilities, 'sortByName');

//output
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Aba ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Mac ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Ronda ) )
```

Working demo: https://repl.it/repls/GruesomeExaltedDevicedriver, After sort the array you can directly use in your `foreach`.